# Deleting first record in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel

When I click on my first record to delete from my application, I get `method not found` error but when I click on another record apart from first one it easily gets deleted.

What is the issue?

Below is the code for Delete:

```
/**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $video = Video::findOrFail($id);
        $delete = $video->delete();
        if ($delete){
            return redirect()->back()->with('trueDelete','Data Not Deleted');
        }else{
            return redirect()->back()->with('falseDelete','Data Deleted Successfully');
        }
    }
```

While clicking on first record from list shows below error,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::get('delete-video/{id}','VideoController@destroy');
```

Comment: No. I am not using resource controller.

Comment: use find($id). instead of findorfail

Comment: please send your route code and your view from where you are sending id in controller

Comment: Route::post('delete-video/{id}','VideoController@destroy'); // DELETE video

Comment: change it to get. @GauravJadhav check my updated code

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that is too much work you are putting into deleting the record. Check out the link below on the official docs to see how to delete in a single line.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#deleting-models

As for the image, you have a

> Method not allowed exception.

This means that, on the place you are deleting from link one, you are using a different route variable than the one specified in the web.php file. Check that you aren't confusing a GET and POST and/or PUT.

Comment: Sir i am facing this issue for first record, rest all records deleted form using same thing.

Comment: Please send a picture of the your web.php and the calling route from the view.

Comment: The method not allowed exception is always sth to do with the routes or CSRF token.

Comment: Route::post('delete-video/{id}','VideoController@destroy'); // DELETE video